# Remove "Scan with Windows Defender" from the Explorer context menu in Windows 10 Creators Update

Tags: windows-explorer, context-menu, windows-defender, windows-10-v1703

I have recently upgraded my windows 10 Pro to the build 1703 aka "Creators Update". How can I remove the "Scan with Windows Defender" item from the Explorer context menu? It seems, old recipes like [this](http://www.askvg.com/tip-remove-scan-with-windows-defender-option-from-context-menu-in-windows-10/) no longer work.

Comment: The old methods still work. Verified it.

Comment: I can also confirm the current methods still work.  Windows Defender didn't receive any functionality changes with regards to this particular feature in 1703

Answer (score 0):

First I tried to launch the "regsvr32 /u" command for the Windows Defender shell extension in PowerShell and got the error 0x8002801c:
[image]
So I thought that this did not work. Also, I could not find the registry keys from the aforementioned article ans asked this question. However, later I found that the "Scan with Windows Defender" item disappeared from the Explorer's context menu!

As an experiment, I opened the traditional command prompt and issued this command to enable the context menu item:

```
regsvr32 /i "C:\Program Files\Windows Defender\shellext.dll"
```

Then deleted it successfully again with the command

```
regsvr32 /u "C:\Program Files\Windows Defender\shellext.dll"
```

This works without any problems if we call this command from cmd.exe.

P.S. Needless to say that I opened PowerShell and Cmd with admin rights.