# Unable to remove "Scan with Windows Defender" from Windows Explorer context menu

Tags: windows-defender

To remove `Scan with Windows Defender` from Windows Explorer's context menu, I obtained `remove Scan with Windows Defender.reg` from [here](https://winaero.com/download-remove-scan-with-windows-defender-context-menu-in-windows-10)

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers\EPP]

[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers\EPP]
```

The first command removes `Scan with Windows Defender` from the file context menu.  The second removes it from the folder context menu.

I ran the above `*.reg` file from an administrator account *without* `regedit` running.  I then fired up `regedit` and checked that the *second* key is gone, rebooted the laptop, and confirmed that `Scan with Windows Defender` is gone from the *folder* context menu.

Perplexingly, however, it is still present in the *file* context menu.  Furthermore, the *folder* key `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers\EPP` still exists, containing value `(Default)` set to `{09A47860-11B0-4DA5-AFA5-26D86198A780}`.

I went back through years of computer housekeeping and found that in [2020](https://superuser.com/questions/1532962/malwarebytes-re-installation-removes-single-file-scan-from-context-menu), `Scan with Windows Defender` was added to the following `shell` keys rather than the above `shellex` keys:

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\WindowsDefender
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\WindowsDefender\Command
```

The asterisk makes it impossible to track down manually.  **Is this why `Scan with Windows Defender` remains in the *file* context menu?**

Before answering, please note from the above 2020 page that `Scan with Windows Defender` was also added to the *folder* context menu via a corresponding `shell` key.  However, the above command specifying a `shellex` key seemingly removed the item from the *folder* context menu (even though the corresponding `shellex` key remains!)

I also tried [this procedure](https://www.intowindows.com/how-to-remove-scan-with-windows-defender-from-context-menu-of-windows-10), which requires removal of key `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{09A47860-11B0-4DA5-AFA5-26D86198A780}`.  On my machine, this does not appear under `CLSID`.

[This page](https://www.ampercent.com/remove-scan-windows-defender-context-menu-windows-10/17882) additionally says to try `regsvr32 /u "C:\Program Files\Windows Defender\shellext.dll"`, but it generates a `RegSvr32` popup error `The module "c:\Program Fileis\Windows Defender\shellext.dll" was loaded but the call to DllUnregisterServer failed with error code 0x8002801c. For more information about this problem, search online using the error code as a search term.`

I found a bit more about this last solution.  Following the success of [this user](https://superuser.com/a/1214921/767015), I installed before uninstalling, but it didn't work (I got similar error messages after both commands):

```
regsvr32 /i "C:\Program Files\Windows Defender\shellext.dll"
regsvr32 /u "C:\Program Files\Windows Defender\shellext.dll"
```

**What else can I try to remove `Scan with Windows Defender`?**  I suspect that I will have to install Windows Defender before the above solutions can work.  I can no longer find up-to-date information on installing the old Windows Defender.  I suspect that even if I could find it, it will be tricky to replaces the current Microsoft Defender with Windows Defender.

*After* doing that, I will take the next step of installing `Scan with *Microsoft* Defender` on Windows Explorer's context menu.  Microsoft Defender is my current antivirus.

I tried posting this to learn.microsoft.com, but when I submit it, I get a page entitled "404 - Page not found"..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the key that was added to create the entry for scanning with Windows Defender (see originally posted question above), I ran the following *.reg file:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\WindowsDefender]
```

The option to scan with ***Windows*** Defender is now gone from the context menu.

Now back to the original problem: Adding the option to scan with ***Microsoft*** Defender to the context menu.    I used the following procedure:

https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/18145-add-remove-scan-microsoft-defender-context-menu-windows-10-a.html

It didn't immediately work because I had previously blocked it (inadvertently) using Ramesh's procedure at:

https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/remove-scan-with-microsoft-defender-right-click-menu

I had to remove the "Blocked" subkey created by Ramesh's procedure before I could see ***Microsoft*** Defender in the context menu. In this context, the problem with Ramesh's procedure is that it was provided in response to my request to remove (or block) ***Windows*** Defender, which it doesn't do.  As I saw, however, it is very effective at its stated purpose of blocking ***Microsoft*** Defender, which was not what I was seeking.

Comment: My context menu entries are labeled `Scan with Microsoft Defender` and they result from `HKCR\[*|Directory]\ShellEx\ContextMenuHandlers\EPP` keys with the `(Default)` value of `{09A47860-11B0-4DA5-AFA5-26D86198A780}`. I don't have the `Shell\WIndowsDefender\Command` keys....

Comment: @KeithMiller: Could I impose on you to point to the source of the *.reg file for this?  I tried the one [here](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/18145-add-remove-scan-microsoft-defender-context-menu-windows-10-a.html) both as administrator and normal user.  No joy, even after a reboot.  I suspect that there are many ways to install the context menu option, and some might work better than others depending on Windows customizations/updates.

Comment: I simply examined my own registry after your question got me curious. As stated, there were no Defender-related subkeys under the `Shell` key. But I ***did*** have the `ShellEx\ContextMenuHanders\EPP` keys. When I temporarily disabled them by changing the `(Default)` values to `-{09A47860-11B0-4DA5-AFA5-26D86198A780}`, the menu items disappeared. Returning them to their original values restored the menu items.

Comment: But you say the referenced CLSID doesn't appear under `HKCR\CLSID` on your machine. Without that CLSID registered, it's not surprising the menus don't appear..

Comment: OK, thanks for clarifying.  I was tripped up by the `|` symbol in the key that you described, but I get it now.  I also found out why I wasn't seeing the option to scan with Microsoft Defender.  I added this to my answer, along with the solution.  Looks like I was right -- the success of any particular method depends on the OS customizations